# Tracking logged users and users roles

Tags: experience-analytics

Can anyone provide me with working example how to **show analytics** (Visits, Page views, Page views per visit, etc) **for logged users**? As I understand there is no OOB solution, so I've tried to implement flexible dimensions, but didn't found a good examples and failed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are 'logged users'?

Comment: I believe you mean "logged-in users". Maybe this video series is helpful to you: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCW9fiNz3eli8rH9RatXeUQ/videos